# GridView in UpdatePanel changing cell color in onrowdatabound causes viewstate error: Failed to load viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, viewstate

Having been searching for days, but just cant narrow down why. I have read enough about it, and have seen suggestions, but none of them seem to solve this particular issue.

I have a asp.net page with a Gridview control in an updatepanel. Nothing special with the Gridview, a few bound textbox fields. The Gridview gets loaded by a datatable in the code behind.

All works fine until I change the background color of the cells based on one of the Column values. If I remove the code below, then I don't get the viewstate errors.

OnRowDataBound code:

```
    protected void PCM_Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
             //check if we are allowed to edit
            if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DisableUpdateCCCat").ToString() == "Y")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[8].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver; //Silver out Cat column
            }
        }
    }
```

As soon as I apply formatting in the above, and say click the SAVE button, I get the error:

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the
control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when
adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and
position of the controls added during the initial request.
```

Somewhere I did read you need to update the viewstate in the UpdatePanel by

```
UpdatePanel.Update();
```

But the error still occurs.

Any ideas/help?

Any replies much appreciated

Comment: Hello! Created project from scratch according to your description - no problems. Can you post some markup and settungs of ViewState of a page and of a GridView?

Answer (score 0):

protected void PCM_Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

//Try to get the gridview value as below

string  DisableUpdateCCCat = e.Row.Cells[6].Text;

if(DisableUpdateCCCat=="Y")

{

e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;

}

}

}